# python write file (to insert)

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have learned that there are `'r'` mode for read, `'w'` for write, and `'a'` for appending. And we have also have the `'+', 't' 'b'` combination.

if I use 'a' or 'a+', I can only append new writings at the end.
even if I use 'r+', I can only write in specific locations to cover the old content. Example: original 123456, if I `f_obj.seek(2)` and `f_obj.write('abc')`, it will become `12abc6`

So is there a way I can write at `seek(2)` and end up with `12abc3456`?

Comment: No operating system that I've ever heard of has the ability to insert data into the middle of a file.  You'd need to rewrite the entire rest of the file, or better yet write everything to a new file (and then possibly rename it the same as the old file).

Comment: Files are sequences of bytes. You can't insert, only overwrite. This means you need to *move the other bytes you otherwise would overwrite*.